# How to install custom plugin on Google Ghrome Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, chrome

I have a problem while trying to install rutoken plugin for Google Chrome v. 40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

That's what I try:

1. Download plugin from http://www.rutoken.ru/support/download/rutoken-plugin/ and unpack files, so I had librtpkcs11ecp.so, npCryptoPlugin.so files.
2. Create a directory for plugins, in the Google Chrome's installation directory.

   `sudo mkdir /opt/google/chrome/plugins`
3. Copy *.so files to the plugins directory.

Then I've restarted Chrome:

`google-chrome -–enable-plugins`

The problem is that when I run `chrome://plugins/` there is no such plugin in a list.